# Leslie Lamport wins Turing Award

Tags: discussion, contests, fun, package-authors

This "question" is probably off topic for even meta because

- it's not a question really
- and it's not directly related to TeX or the site, but...

I thought I'd mention that Leslie Lamport (creator of LaTeX) [just won the Turing award](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/lamport_1205376.cfm) for his work in distributed computing. This is the second TeX giant (after Knuth) to win a Turing award (neither of them for their work on *-TeX alas).

Comment: [Joseph Wright](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [mentioned the good news in chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14348822#14348822) and even mentioned in [latex site news](http://www.latex-project.org/site-news.html#2014-03-18)  and may be they will make a post at tex.sx blog

Comment: Distributed computing, hah! LaTeX can't even use more than one core in my one computer! ...... I'm kidding obviously.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167405/tex-and-turing-award.

Comment: @Christian I am using since over a year  WriteLaTeX/Overleaf with groups up to 10 people writing on the same reports and home works at the same time... is kind of distributed computing if you consider that we are not on the same continent. we are well distributed :)